# php_oci8_12c.dll - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I am using Windows 7 and php5.6.

`php_oci8_12c.dll` exists but I could not find it. Other modules are normal.

errorlog:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:/Server/bin/ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not
>   be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 5):

A bit late, but I faced the issue and found a possible answer just now.

First, Oracle binaries ([from instant client 12 x86](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)) must be in the system path.

Second (the most vicious), check which VC++ runtime is needed (on Oracle's download page) for this instant client and [install it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

I spent 6 hours on it and finally got it. Even on a Windows 2016 server, VC++ runtimes are not installed by default. It's a real pain to realize that.

Hope this helps